# Cannot see debug bar in laravel 4

Tags: debugging, laravel

debug is set to true, why can I not see the laravel debug bar? Sure it was there when I installed the site.

```
'debug' => true,
```

Comment: Laravel does not have a debugbar by default. Have you installed this? https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Comment: I have the same issue. I have followed the directions to install Debugbar but it isn't injected into the page. Not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The laravel debug bar you're talking about is from Laravel 3.

The debug setting from Laravel 4 is only to show the PHP errors. If it set to false then a user friendly message is shown.

From the config file:

```
   /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Debug Mode
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
    | stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
    | application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
    |
    */
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the debug variable! Now I'm wondering how to turn off the debug bar in staging & production environments though.

Comment: No problem! The configuration files are just PHP files. So you can store the returned array in a variable first, overwrite the `debug` key in a if-else statement based on the environment and then return the array variable. (I.E.: `if($app->environment() !== 'local') { $conf['debug'] = false; }`).